# Prove all right angles are congruent?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

Prove all right angles are congruent.

I only have to prove one side to this argument, so I just need to the the other argument.

So basically, if two angles are right, then they must be congruent is what I am trying to prove.

All I have is my assumption that the two angles are right. And conclusion, therefore the angles are congruent.

Comment: What is your definition of Right Angle?

Comment: an angle that is congruent to one of its supplements

Comment: if it helps, I have already proven that an angle congruent to a right angle, is also a right angle.

Comment: Don't have that yet

Comment: there isn't much of a definition given. Just shows a picture of two lines intersecting at one point and showing the angles that are supplementary and then states, notice every angle has two supplements.

Comment: In the context of Eulid's *Elements*, this is a Postulate.

Comment: We don't know your basic axioms. Actually, Euclid took this as an axiom, so your quest would depend on whether your set of axioms is sufficiently different from Euclid's.

Answer (score 1):

*We say that the angle $\measuredangle AOB$ is the supplement of the angle $\measuredangle Y$ if the latter is congruent to an adjacent angle $\measuredangle BOC$ to $\measuredangle AOB$ such that the points $A$, $O$ and $C$ are colineal.*

Using this definition and the fact that *an angle is Right iff it's congruent to one of its supplements* (by definition), you can prove that all right angles are congruent as follows:

Let $\measuredangle AOB$ be a right angle, then it's congruent to one of its supplements (and therefore to all of them). Let $\measuredangle BOC$ be an adjacent supplement of $\measuredangle AOB$, then $\measuredangle AOB \cong \measuredangle BOC$ and $A$, $0$, $C$ are colineal.

Now let $Y$ be any other right angle and consider $D$ an exterior point of $\measuredangle AOB$ such that $\measuredangle AOD$ is a right angle congruent to $Y$. Here you have to prove that: $B$, $O$ and $D$ are colineal and once you have this prove that $\measuredangle AOB\cong \measuredangle AOD$ (using "vertex opposites" arguments), I'm leaving that to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a right angle as the bisector of a straight angle -  analogous to the idea of folding over a straight edge to get a fold perpendicular to that fold, with the same angle either side of the fold line to the straight line - it is clear that since straight lines are taken as similar, and you can create a straight angle by placing a point on a straight line, all bisectors of straight angles - all right angles  - are also congruent.

Answer (score 0):

A straight angle has two right angles. If two angles are such that a supplement of the one equals itself then each must be a right angle. Since only a single parameter is involved congruence is established.

Answer (score 0):

By supplements do you mean they sum to 180 degrees or would form a line if they were adjacent?  Have you considered a proof by contradiction? I love those!  Then you could assume you have two right angles which are not congruent.  Going that route we are given angle A is a right angle, angle 1 is a right angle, and angle A is not congruent to angle 1.  Then there exists angle B which is a congruent supplement and linear pair to angle A and angle 2 which is a congruent supplement and linear pair to angle 1.  Assuming that all lines are the same degrees (180 or whatever), angle B and angle 2 are both half lines (90 degrees or whatever).  So angle B and angle 2 have the same measure and are congruent, which should bring about our contradiction.  Angle A is congruent to angle B, angle B is congruent to angle 2, angle 2 is congruent to angle 1, so angle A is congruent to angle 1, except that it isn't by definition.  Might have to do a little cleaning up in the middle there if you move from congruence to numbers and back.